# I felt strange about the use of "There appear + Noun"

Tags: word-usage, existentials

I was checking grammatical mistakes in an English article translated from Chinese.

The article is about free trade agreement, and I saw a sentence go like this:

> "USA, Japan, and Canada will be used as examples to analyze if **there appeared certain influence** from TPP and the reasons why TPP did not cause any impact to them."

Another sentence in the article goes:

> "USA is also a TPP country, but Canada’s import from USA did not show obvious changes caused by TPP. **There appeared no sign** that the metal industry had been influenced by the formation of TPP."

I get that "There appear + Noun" might stem from a similar structure as "There goes the boy", but somehow I feel "There appear + Noun" is rarely used and might sound strange. When I googled, I found "It appears to be + Noun/Adjective " or "Noun appears to be + Noun/Adjective" is a more common way to use.

Would anyone tell me how you feel about "There appear + Noun"?
Is that native English or just an alien makeup phrase?

Comment: The meaning of "There appeared" is quite different from "It appeared to be". The first is an *existential construction*. P.S. We almost always use **the** before **USA**.

Comment: Thanks, CopperKettle  :-)  Does that mean "There appeared" is commonly used and is native English?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it is in common use and there's nothing alien about it. (0:

Comment: Thanks again for confirming that for me, CopperKettel ! That solved my question. Now I can feel free to use it.

Comment: @CopperKettle The first isn't technically existential  - unless it is *There appeared to be ...*. It's what we call a presentational construction. Compare *There appears to be a misunderstanding* and *There appeared in the doorway a tall, menacing highwayman*.  They're similar, but not the same! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria: Recalling our "thuzza dozen reasons why thuzza cat on the mat"  exchange. With the doorway example, we have a physical locale. With the misunderstanding example, there's a contextual "locale". With the doorway, "appeared" has a literal meaning and with the context, a figurative one. But is "there" used any differently? Isn't the only difference literal versus figurative?

Comment: "USA, Japan, and Canada will be used as examples to analyze if there appeared certain influence from TPP and the reasons why TPP did not cause any impact to them."  When I see a sentence like this, I know that I am only going to be making guesses at what its author meant.  Does "certain" mean "any" or "specific and undisputable"?  Should "and" be "or"?

Comment: @TRomano Syntacically, *there* is the Subject in both sentences. But notice that the two meanings of the verb *appear* are very different, it's not just a figurative versus literal thing. When the verb *appear* is used like the verb *seem*, the Subject of the appear belongs semantically with the predicate. *She appears to be absent* means *It appears that [she is absent]*. In contrast *She appeared in the doorway* doesn't mean *It appeared that [she was in the doorway]*.

Comment: @TRomano ... That *seem* kind of verb is what's known as a *raising* verb, because it looks as though the Subject of some kind of subordinate clause has been *raised* to become the Subject of the main clause. Now we use *there* in existential sentences with verbs like *appear* and move the *there* from the  subordinate clause to the main clause *It appeared [there was a problem]* ---> *There appeared to be a problem*. Notice that we need the verb *BE* there in the subordinate clause ...

Comment: @TRomano  However, if we use the other sense of *appear* as in *A genie appeared in the doorway*, then we don't use the verb *BE* if we use a presentational construction. The only verb we need is *APPEAR*; this verb has real meaning on its own: *There appeared in the doorway a genie*. Notice that there is only one clause/verb here, unlike with the other construction. Now the OP's examples are trying to use the presentational structure but with the *SEEM* /raising sense of *APPEAR*.

Comment: @Araucaria Perzackly. All that  (with perhaps a little deference to the nonspecialist) would make a Very Useful Answer.

Comment: @StoneyB I might try and do it in my breaks, but no promises Am on a mission to write eighteen thousand words in the next two weeks ... My appearances on SE are just avoidance at the mo : /

Comment: @StoneyB You could write one though! And I could read it in one of my breaks :)

Comment: "Now the OP's examples are trying to use the presentational structure but with the SEEM /raising sense of APPEAR".    I understood them to mean "whether there appeared *in the data provided by these examples* any evidence of ...." . Not the "seems to be" meaning.

Comment: @TRomano I understand the first as "*The USA, Japan, and Canada will be used as examples to analyze whether there appears to have been any influence from the TPP*" and the second as "*There appeared to be no sign that the metal industry had been influenced by the formation of the  TPP*". (shrugs)

Comment: @TRomano It's a bit difficult to tell for sure ...

Comment: @Araucaria: Since the passage in the OP was about data analysis, and **appeared in the data** is such a commonplace expression (analogous to "appeared in the doorway"), I gravitated to the non-raised form.

Comment: @TRomano but you also need to insert the phrase *evidence of* to make it work. "Influence" can't appear in the data, it seems to me.

Comment: @Araucaria. Sure it can, in dataspeak, though in normaltalk we'd say "signs of influence".

Comment: Guys. Initially I was confused because when I looked up the dictionary it doesn't mention any usage of the sentence structure "There appear + Noun". (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/appear)  Therefore according to what I've learned from the dictionary, <He "appeared" > means <He "showed up"> , and <He appears (to be) confused > means <He "seems" confused>. And as an extension, <There "appears to be" a mistake; It appears (to be) wrong> means <It "seems" wrong>.

Comment: But honestly, to me, <There "appeared" no sign> makes no sense to me because firstly the dictionary does not admit the existence of such linguistic structure and because secondly there seems no way to confirm whether the "appear" in the sentence means "show up" or "seem" .  That is why I brought up this topic for discussion and want to know if most people would think "There appear + Noun" is a good language structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel "There appear + Noun" is rarely used and might sound strange.

**You are incorrect.**

Even though that phrase is not rarely used, I would say that by convention "There appeared ..." is generally followed be "to be". I think the text is not perfectly translated and that the correct way of writing these particular phrases that you highlighted in bold are as follows:

> if there appeared to be certain influence

and

> There appeared to be no sign

respectively.

---

## Examples

However, this does *not* mean that "There appeared + Noun/Adjective" is rarely used, nor does it necessarily sound strange when it is used correctly. Bear in mind these valid examples (the first two were also mentioned in the comments):

> There appeared in the doorway a genie.
>
> There appeared in the doorway a tall, menacing highwayman.
>
> I appeared as if from nowhere.
>
> It would appear that there was no one at the front door.
>
> There appeared, somehow, to be another room in the house.

---

### Bottom Line

"There appeared + Noun/Adjective" can be used correctly in certain circumstances, but most of the time it tends to be followed by "to be".