# There appear + noun (what is the meaning)

Tags: usage

I have read this thread [I felt strange about the use of "There appear + Noun"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77451/i-felt-strange-about-the-use-of-there-appear-noun) but it's still a murky thing for me.

If I want to say that a number of people who get interested in learning a new programming language have been growing, can I use "there appear" construction?

> There appear more and more people who get interested in learning a new programming language.

> There appear more and more banks which are willing to provide this service.

If this construction doesn't make sense, what can be used instead of it?

UPDATE:
I have found this sentence in press:

**Of course, among the American politicians there appear more and more people who think realistically.**

How would you justify "there appear more and more people who think"?

Is "there" a dummy pronoun or demonstrating pronoun?

Answer (score 3):

No, your examples are not idiomatic. You could begin them with "There appear **to be**...", with the meaning "It seems to me that there are more and more..." This usage describes your impression of the situation rather than an established fact.

Comment: OK. What if it doesn't seem to be, but it is a fact. How can I say that? More and more people appear who... ?

Comment: If it's a fact, you don't need to use _appear_ at all. _More and more people are becoming interested in learning a new programming language._

Comment: What about banks? More and more banks ...

Comment: I didn't think it necessary to spell out that the same applies to both sentences. _More and more banks are willing..._